# Couldnt run eclipse che on kubernetes

Tags: eclipse-che

Cloned che source code (from github) from master branch. Tried to run eclipse che as shown below:
`helm upgrade --install che --namespace che --set cheImage=eclipse/che-server:nightly --set global.cheWorkspacesNamespace="che" --set global.ingressDomain=192.168.99.107.nip.io ./`

The following error is shown:
`Release "che" does not exist. Installing it now.
Error: render error in "che/templates/configmap.yaml": template: che/templates/configmap.yaml:87:14: executing "che/templates/configmap.yaml" at <.Values.che.workspace.devfileRegistryUrl>: nil pointer evaluating interface {}.workspace`

Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems there is a bug in current version of helm chart in upstream. Issue was already logged: https://github.com/eclipse/che/issues/13558.

If you want to do quick workaround, you can go to `deploy/kubernetes/helm/che/values.yaml` and uncomment lines 70-74 and deployment should work and the che-server will use those URL's for plugin and devfile registries. If you want to provide your own registries, just change those values.

Radim